# InvalidUseOfMatchers even when no of arguments and matchers are correct

Tags: junit, mockito

I am new to Mockito , looks like i m missing some basic stuff.

Here is my test method :

```
 List<FundingSrc> fslist = new ArrayList<FundingSrc>();
        FundingSrc fs1 = new FundingSrc();
        FundingSrc fs2 = new FundingSrc();
        fs1.setMtcn("111");
        fs2.setMtcn("2222");
        fslist.add(fs1);
        fslist.add(fs2);
        System.out.println(fslist.size());
        lenient().when(fsdao.getAllSettledTxns(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(fslist);
        assertThat(fsdao.getAllSettledTxns(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).isNotNull();
        assertEquals(fslist.size(), fsdao.getAllSettledTxns(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()).size());
```

getAllSettledTxns has only 2 arguments . But still i am getting below error at line :

```
lenient().when(fsdao.getAllSettledTxns(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(fslist);
```

:

20:28:14.141 [main] INFO com.example.demo.Repository.FundingSrcDAO - ### In method FundingSrcDAO.getAllSettledTxns ######
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.105 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.demo.FileSimulatorTest
test  Time elapsed: 1.104 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:

Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
-> at com.example.demo.FileSimulatorTest.test(FileSimulatorTest.java:53)
-> at com.example.demo.FileSimulatorTest.test(FileSimulatorTest.java:53)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
//incorrect:
someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");

Comment: Would help if you can also paste your actual code for which you are writing test class.

Comment: I feel this line is not correct  'assertThat(fsdao.getAllSettledTxns(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).isNotNull();' What exactly are you trying to verify. Are you trying to assert that this method was indeed called ?